# Javascript Syntax error: missing ) after argument list: on col 61

Tags: javascript

Okay so here is my code, anyone know how to fix this? it won't even run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Hiding Game</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="proj3.css" />
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
        document.writeln("<table>")
        document.writeln("<th>Day</th>")
        document.writeln("<th>Hiding Place</th>")
        document.writeln("<th>Explosion</th>")  
    do{
        counter = counter + 1
        var hide = Number(prompt("It is day " + counter + ".  Where will you hide (1, 2, 3, or 4)?"));
        var explosionLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            if (hide <1 || hide >4) {
                alert("That is not a valid choice.")
            }
            else {
                alert("Hiding place " + explosionLocation + " has exploded!")
                if (hide !== explosionLocation) {
                    alert("You have survived!")
                    document.writeln("<tr><th>" + counter + "</th><td class='survived'>" + hide + "</td><td class='survived'>" + explosionLocation + "</td></tr>")
                }
                else { 
                alert("You have died.  You survived for a total of " counter - 1 " days.")
                document.writeln("<tr><th>" + counter + "</th><td class='died'>" + hide + "</td><td class='survived'>" + explosionLocation + "</td></tr>"")
                document.writeln("<tr colspan='3'><td>"'Survived for ' + counter - 1 + ' days""</td></tr>")
                }
            }
    } while (explosionLocation !== hide)




</script>
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. The code is supposed to generate a game where the user tries to avoid a 1 in 4 chance of dying.

Comment: You have a typo at the end of that line. One too many quotation marks.

Comment: You should learn to troubleshoot your code. This is the sort of thing that you'll be doing all the time when programming. If you just can't spot the error, try commenting out lines around the given area until the error disappears, then carefully examine your syntax.

Comment: I think you should tryed a bit more harder before posting your question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the bare minimum to get the code running:

```
var counter = 0;
    document.writeln("<table>")
    document.writeln("<th>Day</th>")
    document.writeln("<th>Hiding Place</th>")
    document.writeln("<th>Explosion</th>")
do{
    counter = counter + 1
    var hide = Number(prompt("It is day " + counter + ".  Where will you hide (1, 2, 3, or 4)?"));
    var explosionLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        if (hide <1 || hide >4) {
            alert("That is not a valid choice.")
        }
        else {
            alert("Hiding place " + explosionLocation + " has exploded!")
            if (hide !== explosionLocation) {
                alert("You have survived!")
                document.writeln("<tr><th>" + counter + "</th><td class='survived'>" + hide + "</td><td class='survived'>" + explosionLocation + "</td></tr>")
            }
            else {
            alert("You have died.  You survived for a total of " + (counter - 1) + " days.")
            document.writeln("<tr><th>" + counter + "</th><td class='died'>" + hide + "</td><td class='survived'>" + explosionLocation + "</td></tr>")
            document.writeln("<tr colspan='3'><td>Survived for " + (counter - 1) + " days</td></tr>")
            }
        }
} while (explosionLocation !== hide)
```

The three key lines that were changed are these:

```
            alert("You have died.  You survived for a total of " + (counter - 1) + " days.")
            document.writeln("<tr><th>" + counter + "</th><td class='died'>" + hide + "</td><td class='survived'>" + explosionLocation + "</td></tr>")
            document.writeln("<tr colspan='3'><td>Survived for " + (counter - 1) + " days</td></tr>")
            }
```

A few quotes were mismatched, and you need to place parenthesis around `counter - 1` if you'd like it to actually do the math on it. Otherwise, JavaScript gets confused what you're asking of it when you place `-` in the middle of combining strings.

Comment: ok thanks! and do you know if there is any way to make it just say "day" if the outcome is only 1 day?

Comment: You would have to wrap that part of the code in an if statement and check if the outcome is only one day before deciding to output "day" or "days".

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to concat the string with + symbol in the last 3 alerts

```
alert("You have died.  You survived for a total of " + (counter - 1) + " days.")
document.writeln("<tr><th>" + counter + "</th><td class='died'>" + hide + "</td><td class='survived'>" + explosionLocation + "</td></tr>")
document.writeln("<tr colspan='3'><td>Survived for " + (counter - 1) + " days</td></tr>")
```

Comment: ok thanks! and do you know if there is any way to make it just say "day" if the outcome is only 1 day